# Show $(1 - o(1/n))^n = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

Question : In one the proofs that I am trying to understand, the identity
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 - o(1/n))^n = 1
$$
appeared and I could not understand why.

Known information : In particular, it is known $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - 1/n)^n = 1/e$. It is not clear how $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - o(1/n))^n = 1$ instead?

Background : I am new to the concept of little-o notations.

Comment: This has no sense. For example, $(1 - 1/n)^n = 1/e$ is simply not true (just take $n=1$). There is at least missing a $"\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}"$.

Comment: Recall that by definition $o(1/n)=\omega(n)\frac1n$ with  $\omega(n) \to 0$.

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\left(1 + \frac{a}{n}\right)^n \to e^a$? Can you go through that proof and see what changes in your situation?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Sorry about the confusion, it is fixed.

Comment: @user Could you clarify the hint? I don't see how $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 - \omega(n)\frac{1}{n})^n = 1$? If one wants to use L'hopital, don't we need to know if $\omega(n)$ is differentiable or not?

Comment: Could use continuity of exponentiation and evaluate $\lim n\ln (1-o(1/n))$ instead

Comment: @PartialT For example $$\left(1 -\frac{ \omega(n)}{n}\right)^n=\left[\left(1 - \frac{\omega(n)}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{ \omega(n)}}\right]^ {\omega(n)}$$

Comment: To make yourself more comfortable, just replace "$o(1/n)$" with a function $f(n)$, and wherever necessary use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{1/n} = 0$. For example, here you need to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-f(n))^{\frac 1n}$ for such a function. As a consequence of $\lim_{n \to \infty} nf(n)=0$, you can prove that for all constants $a>0$, $f(n) \leq \frac{a}{n}$ for large enough $n$, and for all $a<0$, $f(n) \geq \frac{a}{n}$ for large enough $n$. Using this, you can compare the limit in question to $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac an)^{\frac 1n}$ whose value is known.

Comment: When confronted with limits like this one using exponentiation, it's a good reflex to rewrite expressions of the form $x^a$ as $\exp(a\ln(x))$.

Comment: Or $$\left(1 -\frac{ \omega(n)}{n}\right)^n=e^{n\log \left(1 -\frac{ \omega(n)}{n}\right)}$$

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer So I can sandwich $\lim_n (1 - f(n))^\frac{1}{n}$ by $e^{-a}$ and $e^{a}$ for $a > 0$. Then $a \to 0$?

Comment: @PartialT Precisely!

Comment: Although the argument is not as easy as written, it requires a little more subtlety, but at least it explains very clearly why the answer is $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f\in o(1/n)$, i.e, $nf(n)\to 0$. This also implies $f(n)\to 0$.  From $\frac{\ln (1-x)}{-x}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1$ it follows that
$$ \lim _{n\to\infty} n\ln (1-f(n)) = \lim _{n\to\infty} -nf(n) = 0. $$
Conclude desired result from continuity of exponentiation.

Comment: Could you explain how $\frac{\log(1 - x)}{-x} \to 1$ make the first equality?

Comment: @PartialT Equivalent quantities are interchangeable in limit calculations. In this case we have $-\ln (1-f(n))/f(n)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.